# I dont know how to install SGI IRIX operating system

Tags: sgi

I just bought an SGI Indy computer off of Ebay. The computer works, but I do not know how to netboot one of the computers. Since I do not have an external disk drive (but I do have disk drives from old computers, but they do not plug into the computer with the correct ports), I cannot install them with some disks that I have. I, then, resorted to trying to install the machine over a network. I tried, first, to install it over the DIMA server, but the computer would not recognize it. I am not sure if the DIMA VM was not connecting to the internet. I then tried the netboot appliance on github, and that also did not work, because I could not find the IP address of the computer.

when I let the computer do it's normal boot when the ethernet cable is hooked up.
[image]

P.S. I do not have a mouse, so I just use the keyboard to move the mouse around, or use the keyboard keys. I bought a USB to PS2 converter, but the motherboard is not supporting the mouse, so that is why I have to use the keyboard.....

Here is a photo without the ethernet cable hooked up...

[image]

The "ALERT:ec0" reappears in a new line every few minutes.

The ports:

[image]

The USB to PS2 converter:

[image]

From these things, I am guessing that the computer already has Irix installed, but I want to reinstall it because I do not know how to fix the kernel error.

The ports with the ethernet cable:

[image]

The ethernet cable has been hooked into a Windows 10 laptop and an IMac, and I received the same results...

I then ran to the DINA (deBugs IRIX Netboot Appliance), and I do not think it was connected to the Internet (feel free to ask about that). I really do not actually know how to use it, I just attempted to figure it out by watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-7vCz7oxSg&t=3s) (which did not give me much help because I did not see the ports or what he did before the video).

I still, after the video do not know how to use the appliance. The computer works perfectly, with an R4X00. ALso, some helpful information could be that the timezone is PST8PDT.

The boot noise also works because I reset the environment variables (which did not do anything, it just turned the volume up a little bit in the computer).

There are no (as I can see) IP addresses on the computer.

Please Help!
Thanks!

Comment: You can add two things to help us answer your question: photos (to the ports, preferably through the Add Image UI so they're on the `i.stack.imgur.com` domain) and links (to the programs you've talked about). Also, the [tour] if you haven't read it.

Comment: The SGI computer just says It is not connected to the internet, and it cannot find any files.

Comment: So it's already running an operating system... Could you take some pictures of the screen and the ports please?

Comment: I just am having an issue with the appliance. When I first got the computer, it would report (when I would have the ethernet attached to the router; I am not sure if I attach it to the router or the computer with the VM on it...): "lboot: WARNING: kernel seems current but has a modification time in the future <nextline> add net default: gateway 192.168.1.1

Comment: It does not actually say “next line”, it just returns to the next line of the screen.

Comment: The warning you're seeing is probably because the system clock is returning an older date than the timestamp on the kernel file.  This can happen, e.g., if the RTC battery is dead.  The system will likely run fine once it picks up the time and date from NTP.  If this is the case then the long-term fix would be to replace the RTC battery (typically a CR2032 coin cell).

Comment: The next line is saying that the system thinks it's on the 192.168.1.n network and is sending all traffic destined for other networks to your router at 192.168.1.1.  If this isn't your network and router address you'll want to adjust the network settings once the system has booted.

Comment: As for the mouse, USB to PS2 converters are typically passive devices that only work with mice that are designed to speak both protocols.  IOW, if the converter came with the mouse it should work fine with that mouse but might not work with others.  If you have other mice you could try plugging them into the converter; one of them may work.

Comment: Question: Do you eventually get a login prompt?  If so, can you log in as root?

Comment: Maybe take a look here: [Installing IRIX over Network](https://software.majix.org/irix/install-network.shtml)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  It seems like the system is booting into the OS (no reïnstall needed) and is seeing that the network cable is plugged in.  Is the root issue that you don't have network access after the system boots?

Comment: No I do not get a login prompt. None of my mice work. The battery is not dead because I set it to January 1st, 2000 2 days ago, and now it reads January 3, 2000.

Comment: Also, Raffzahn, I do not know the IP Address of my Indy. And I also only have .iso files to the install. Surely they would work, but when I try to open them in Windows, it claims that they are corrupt, even though I got them from WinWorldPC.com. From my knowledge, I think that those images are only compatible with FreeBSD, but that is probably not what the issue is...

Comment: Actually, Raffzahn, should I use Debian for the netboot?

Comment: My real question is, "what operating system do I need to do this?". I need to know if I should use a Unix based operating system, a Unix operating system, Mac, or Windows. Can I use a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox or VMware.

Comment: To Alex Hajnal- I am not sure what the issue is. I have never used an IRIX machine before, much less troubleshoot issues.

Comment: I know how to change the time, it just has date [mmddhhmm [ccyy|yy] [.ss]] format.

Comment: OK, the date warning can be safely ignored.  Based on what I've read it sounds like there is probably a fresh install of Irix on there.  See if you can get into single user mode.  When booting you should see "stop for maintance"; at this point hit Escape then choose "Enter Command Monitor", type "single" and hit Enter.  The system should quickly boot (with no network) then you should be prompted to enter the root password.  In a fresh install there is no root password so just hit enter.  ...

Comment: ... At this point you should end up in a root shell.  I'm not sure exactly what the prompt is for the Irix root shell but it should end in a # character.  Let me know if you get this far.  (Also, do you have any Unix or Linux experience?)

Comment: @AlexHajnal: Your comments are enough for an answer, even though it's just partial at this point, but it will already be valuable for anyone else in a similar situation. You can edit your answer and add to it as the OP gives more info.

Comment: @AlexHajnal The site's autoflagger is complaining about the sheer number of comments posted here; It'd be great if you could roll them up into an answer (as dirkt says) so that the error goes away.

Comment: [Here's a chat-room with all the comments as of this time](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82923/discussion-on-question-by-rjhwinner03-i-dont-know-how-to-install-sgi-irix-operat). Comments posted after this point will not be preserved; use the chat room if you want to keep them.

Comment: I do not want to answer my question because I have not finished asking questions...

Comment: To Alex Hanjal- there is a root password that is preventing me from getting into the computer. Is there a way I can remove all passwords?

Comment: @rjhwinner03 Let's continue this in the answer I posted below.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Now that I've aggregated my comments into an answer should I nuke all my comments above?

Comment: @AlexHajnal Yeah; if you flag rjhwinner's comments in the thread as No Longer Needed I'll delete them too.

Answer (score 5):

**Note: This answer is a work in progress**

Based on the info in your question it appears that the system powers on, starts to boot of the hard drive, and probably has a working network interface.  This is good since the hardware appears to be fully functional.  Regarding the boot messages you're seeing:

- `lboot: WARNING: kernel seems current but has a modification time in the future`
  This warning is probably shown because the system clock is returning an older date than the timestamp on the kernel file. This can happen, e.g., if the RTC battery is dead or simply if the RTC's date is set to a date older than the kernel. The system will likely run fine once it picks up the time and date from NTP. If the RTC always returns the same date and time at boot then the long-term fix would be to replace the RTC battery (typically a CR2032 coin cell).
- `add net default: gateway 192.168.1.1`
  This is shown when the networking set-up script runs.  The system is saying that it thinks it's on the 192.168.1.n network and is sending all traffic destined for other networks to your router at 192.168.1.1. If this isn't your network and router address you'll want to adjust the network settings once the system has booted.  For a fresh install, Irix uses the address 192.168.1.2/24 as the system IP address.  This is consistent with the gateway address show above.

**Booting into single-user mode**

Given that the system appears to be booting off the hard drive and at least some of the OS is coming up, it's likely that a reïnstall won't be necessary.  Given the reported network address, you're probably looking at a fresh install of Irix.  Since the system won't complete booting in its current state you'll want to try booting into single user mode so that you can poke around a bit and find out what state it's in, change settings, etc.  To do this:

- When booting you should see `stop for maintenance`; at this point hit *`Escape`* then choose `Enter Command Monitor`, type `single` and hit *`Enter`*.
- The system should quickly boot (with no network) then you should be prompted to enter the root password. In a fresh install there is no root password so just hit *`Enter`*.  If this doesn't work then you could also try some of the obvious password possibilities such as `root`, `password`, or maybe `wheel`.
  Note: If none of the passwords work then you'll need to clear the root password in `/etc/passwd` either by booting into SASH from the `stop for maintenance` menu (which I believe needs a CDROM to function) or by pulling the hard drive and using a Linux system with a SCSI card to mount the drive's filesystem.  Alternatively, you might be able to netboot the Indy and edit the password file from there.   If none of this works and you still can't log in, you'll need to do a reïnstall of the system.
- At this point you should end up in a root shell. I'm not sure exactly what the prompt is for the Irix root shell but it should end in a `#` character.  Take a look around and see what state the system is in.  The [Unix Rosetta Stone](https://web.archive.org/web/20180903233056/http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) might come in handy.

**Network booting / DINA**

If you're having trouble getting the Indy working with DINA, the issue may be that your LAN's DHCP server is conflicting with DINA's.  Try putting the machine running DINA and the Indy on their own network (either through a switch or directly together using a crossover cable) and trying again.  [A nice tutorial on using DINA can be found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180910010626/https://sites.google.com/a/harrydebug.com/dina/).  See also [irixboot](https://github.com/halfmanhalftaco/irixboot) and [Installing IRIX over a Network](https://web.archive.org/web/20170621103651/http://software.majix.org/irix/install-network.shtml).

**Mouse**

USB to PS2 converters are typically passive devices that only work with mice that are designed to speak both protocols. IOW, if the converter came with the mouse it should work fine with that mouse but might not work with others. If you have other mice you could try plugging them into the converter; one of them may work.

**Questions for the OP**

- Are you able to log in in single user mode?  If not, do you have access to a SCSI CDROM drive that is compatible with the Indy (either externally or internally)?
- What exactly is the current state of the system?  e.g. Does it boot fully or does it get stuck after bringing up the network?

Comment: I have only Ubuntu experience, but I have done a lot of research on MIPS. Also, thanks to everyone for assisting me!

Comment: I do have a SCSI CDROM drive, but it is inside of a Windows Me Compaq Presario computer. I do know how to take out the cd-rom drive, but I do not know how to put it into a SGI computer without the external drive cable. Maybe I could attach it inside the computer, but it would be very dangerous, I feel, to the computer and it's interior.

Comment: I have tested the CDROM drive in the Compaq and it still works... I know this because I installed Empire Earth on that computer with the disks, and they worked.

Comment: I went to WinWorldPC and downloaded some Irix ISO images, and I am currently asking them questions about them on the Forums... You can find the question here:                   
https://forum.winworldpc.com/discussion/10717/how-do-i-burn-the-irix-iso-files-version-6-5-to-a-disk-and-what-type-of-drive/p1?new=1

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, first try logging from the console.  If that doesn't work either try netbooting to get a root shell or install the Indy's disk in a Linux box and edit `/etc/passwd` from there.  If all else fails do a full install.  If the Compaq box you've got really does have a SCSI bus (I find it a bit surprising) you could transfer the Indy's disk there and boot a Linux live CD to do the file edits.

Comment: SCSI connections are similar to IDE ones just with a 50-pin cable instead of a 40-pin one.  Make sure the bus is properly terminated (there should be a resistor pack at the end of the chain) and change the drive's SCSI ID if there's a conflict (be sure to note the old ID so you can change it back when you're done).

Comment: Is the `ALERT: ec0: no carrier: check Ethernet cable` from the second screen-shot significant? I've hardly any experience with Irix, but this suggests more than just not finding an IP address ... if "_The ethernet cable has been hooked into a Windows 10 laptop and an IMac_" means "_directly connected_" then perhaps a hub or a cross-over network cable is needed?

Comment: For the RTC battery, these systems have a Dallas Timekeeper chip. There's no visible coin cell battery, it's inside the Timekeeper chip package, which can be replaced/bypassed with the use of a Dremel and some soldering.

Comment: In order to boot from a CDROM, the SCSI drive might need to support 512 byte sectors, the same as with old Sun machines.

Comment: Ok, The CDROM thing is out the window. The ports do not fit... How do I netboot?

Comment: I now get an error when I netboot that says: cannot load network(0)bootp()192.168.1.100:/irix/6.5/disk1/dist/sa(sashARCS) -- could not connect to server.

Comment: @rjhwinner03 That looks like it's a problem on the server.  Your Irix box has got an IP and BOOTP is specifying a root image to load.  It doesn't look like the TFTP server is running though.  Check the server and make sure the TFTP dæmon is running.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the error. I had to plug in the ethernet cable, change the IP, then click install... I then had to quickly unplug the ethernet cable and throw it into the LAN port in my router.

Thanks a million to those who helped, I would have never figured it out without you!